# TexShop began crashing…

Tags: texshop, mactex, macos

I've used LaTex steadily over many years now, with TexShop. Today, when I tried to use for first time in a while, it crashed repeatedly. I've updated MacTex to 2021 and independently downloaded the latest version of TexShop 4.66. I'm on macOS Catalina 10:15.7.

It now crashes repeatedly, as soon as a document is opened, which now happens automatically, as I ticked the option to 'Open with a blank document' (when it was still possible to access Preferences.)

I'm unsure what else to try. Can anyone kindly point me in a helpful direction?

If it means anything to anyone this is from the crash report:

```
Application Specific Information: Crashing on exception: The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window.
```

Comment: That's very helpful; thank you. I'm on the TexShop website (https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/installing.html), which offers some earlier version, but not the one you mention… is there something I'm missing or another source towards which you could direct me?

Comment: I might not remember the version number correctly. Sorry about that. According to https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html, it should be version 4.44.

Comment: That's fine; I downloaded 4.15 and at least was able to open a blank page. I'll try 4.44 and see how I go…

Comment: so far so good; version 4.44 is working adequately for my purposes — yay! back in the game! cheers

Comment: Happy to know that!!

Comment: cheers! actually it's working with 4.15 for some reason, but maybe it'll move to 4.44 when I close and update (both on system presently)

Comment: The latest version of TeXShop 4.66 and should run on your system.

Comment: It was 4.66 version that totally failed to open on system.