# TeXShop Editor Window does not open

Tags: editors

recently the TeX Shop editor window does not open as usual, e.g. when clicking on the
file <name.tex> icon. Neither it does open with a command from a menu. This may be connected with Mac OS 11.1 that I use on MacBook Pro 16'' (2019). Does anyone else face this problem?

Thanks and best wishes,
Hans

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. What version of TeXShop are you using?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606834/texshop-began-crashing might be related.