# TexShop keeps crashing

Tags: texshop, bugs

Any version of TexShop after 4.44 crashes as soon as opened.

I'm trying to run TexShop 4.68 on macOS 11.6, but it crashes as soon as opened.
The system report about this crash says:

> Crashing on exception: The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window.
> <TSTextEditorWindow: 0x7f9ec368df70> 0x2cef (11503) {{1920, -100}, {1024, 761}} Untitled en

This happens with any version after 4.44, and have had this problem for a while (since version 4.44 has been updated).
For now, I keep using TexShop 4.44, which I regularly recover from backup.

P.S.
I know that this question is a replica of
[TexShop began crashing…](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606834/texshop-began-crashing)
But that question seems to be dormant and it's not clear if the problem has been solved or not. I wanted to comment or upvote it, but I don't have enough "reputation", which I can get by asking a question... and here we are.

**Solution:**
I deleted (or moved away from its folder) the file `~/Library/Preferences/TeXShop.plist`,
which was broken in a mysterious manner.
It was not my idea: thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: First try opening TeXShop while holding down the Option key. If that doesn't help I suggest you get in contact with the author of TeXaShop at `koch@uoregon.edu`. Please include a description and full crash report.